# How to convert NL to SQL

Tags: python, sql, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I successfully tokenized, removed stop words, completed POS and NER but now I am facing a problem in generating SQL queries. I am not able to convert NER to SQL.

I used have used the NLTK package.

My parser code:

```
from nltk import load_parser
cp = load_parser('grammars/book_grammars/sql0.fcfg')
query = 'What cities are located in India'
trees = list(cp.parse(query.split()))
print(trees)

answer = trees[0].label()['SEM']
answer = [s for s in answer if s]
print(answer)

q = ' '.join(answer)
print(q)
```

My code till NER:

```
contentArray = ['show sales from Delhi']
def processLanguage():
    try:
        for item in contentArray:
            tokenized = nltk.word_tokenize(item)
            
            stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
            word_tokens = word_tokenize(item)
            filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words]
            filtered_sentence = []
            for w in word_tokens:
                if w not in stop_words:
                    filtered_sentence.append(w)

            #print(word_tokens)
            print(filtered_sentence)
            
            tagged = nltk.pos_tag(filtered_sentence)
            print(tagged)
            
            ne_tree = ne_chunk(tagged)
            print(ne_tree)

            iob_tagged = tree2conlltags(ne_tree)
            print (iob_tagged)
            ne_tree = conlltags2tree(iob_tagged)
            print (ne_tree)

            namedEnt = nltk.ne_chunk(tagged)
            namedEnt.draw()

 



    except Exception as e:
        print (str(e))


processLanguage()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not able"? What error do you get?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have 1 error on my parser "trees = list(cp.parse(query.split()))". It says: "Grammar does not cover some of the input words: "'India'""